# C Power function negative exponent without pow()

Tags: c, function, exponent

I'm trying to make a little power calculator for learning purposes  in C without using pow,
but it always returns 0.00 when exponent is negative, please help.

full code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
//*  power caculator function

int power(x,y)
{
   float p=1.00;
   int i;
    if (y<0){
        y=-1*y;
        x=1/x;
    }
    for (i=1;i<=y;i++)
    {
        p=p*x;
    }

return p;
}



//*  main gets input, calls power caculator and prints result'
int main()
{
int b;
int e;
float p;
printf("enter base");
scanf("%d",&b);
printf("enter exponent");
scanf("%d",&e);
p=power(b,e);
printf("%d to the power of %d is %.2f",b,e,p);
return 0;
}
//* I am NOOB
```

Comment: `int power(x,y)` what are the argument types? Also please pay attention to compiler warnings. By omitting the type, then compiler assumes they are `int`. You did supply `int` arguments but `x=1/x;` assumes integer division.

Comment: What is `1/x` for any `x > 1`?

Comment: pow() works just fine with negative exponents, but then you chop them off by declaring your function to return int.

Comment: Truncation is a problem apart from the other basic ones. 1 divided by any int is 0.

Comment: The return value of `power()` is `int`. So even when you get the argument types (or the casting) right, any negative power (result < 1) will return `0`.

Comment: @infinite almost, but not quite.  `1` and `-1` will give you a different result.  And `0` makes babies cry.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons I tried 1/i, 1/(-i), -1/(i), -1/(-i) where i is an integer other than 0 and got the same result 0 on gcc 6.3

Comment: @infinite `1` is an integer other than 0.  I would be very interested in a system where `1/1` comes out to `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using integers to hold decimal values, in this case with x and with the return type of the power function.

try:

```
float power(x,y)
{
   float p=1.00;
   float xx = (float)x;
   int i;
    if (y<0){
        y=-1*y;
        xx=1/xx;
    }
    for (i=1;i<=y;i++)
    {
        p=p*xx;
    }

return p;
}
```

Comment: Ah I SEE NOW! Thanks Miguel!

Comment: Great! Best regards!

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I assume it's because the function still has not explicitly defined the types of `x` and `y`.

Comment: yea... defining types for parameters will help a lot... I agree.. I'll down vote myself... jejeje

Answer (score 0):

define data types of x and y explicitly and then adjust the return data type.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Hope this is useful to someone in the future :-) */

double power (double n, int p){
    int i;
    double pow = 1;


    if (p > 0)
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= p; i++)
        {
            pow *= n;

        }   
            return pow;
    } 
    else
    {
        for (i = 0; i > p; i--)
        {
            pow *= 1/n;
        }
            return pow;
    }
}
```